# Why do I encounter "Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" when resetting a password via Graph API

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have cloned the [MS Identity DotNetCore B2C Account Management](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management) code sample and configured it for my B2C tenant. The get user and delete user commands all work. However when I try to use command `[5] Update user password` I encounter this error:

> ```
>  Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
>  Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
> ```

The description of [this Microsoft support issue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3004133/authorization-requestdenied-error-message-when-you-try-to-change-a-pas) for Office 365 seems to overlap with what I'm encountering. The implication seems to be that an admin account is at a higher level than the application can touch because the application isn't an admin within AD.

So, the application could manage normal non-admin users, but not admin accounts?  Am I understanding that correctly. And if so is there a way to elevate my registered application's privileges so as to update passwords for admins as well as non-admin accounts?

The only changes to the sample were in `appsettings.json` and entailed the expected customization of values for `"TenantId"`, `"AppId"`, and `"ClientSecret"`.

I've registered an application and granted the following permissions for Graph API:

- AuditLog.ReadAll
- Directory.ReadWriteAll
- UserManageIdentities.All
- User.ReadWrite.All

[image: Screenshot of Microsoft Graph API permissions]

This is the code attempting the user password update:

```cs
        public static async Task SetPasswordByUserId(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter user object ID: ");
            string userId = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter new password: ");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine($"Looking for user with object ID '{userId}'...");

            var user = new User
            {
                PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration,DisableStrongPassword",
                PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
                {
                    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
                    Password = password,
                }
            };

            try
            {
                // Update user by object ID
                await graphClient.Users[userId]
                   .Request()
                   .UpdateAsync(user);

                Console.WriteLine($"User with object ID '{userId}' successfully updated.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the `passwordProfile` of the user, the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission is needed.

See the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions):

[image]

And you should note the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` is the `Delegated permission`, not `Application permission`. It means the permission will not take effect in the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)(the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management) you provided uses it), so when you use the Microsoft Graph SDK, you could not use the [`Client credentials provider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#client-credentials-provider), your option is to use the [`Authorization code provider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#authorization-code-provider)(recommended).

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret) // or .WithCertificate(certificate)
    .Build();

AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes);
```

Comment: One thing I was a little confused by is why the Delegated permissions would play a role.  I got the impression from all docs I read around the sample that it involved only the Application API permissions

Comment: @TrevorReid Yes, there are two types of API permissions, Application permission and Delegated permission, in this case, you need the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All`, which is just existing in the Delegated permissions of MS Graph.